# How is it possible to use tampermonkey to display content from a link to another site in the gitlab wiki?

Tags: tampermonkey, gitlab-ce

In the gitlab wiki it is not possible to use iframes to embed content from another site.
I would like to be able to put a link to that content onto the wiki and diplay it within the site.
For security reasons it's not possible serversided but in my own browser i should be able to do that.
My idea was to use tampermonkey to convert a link with a special tag into an iframe.

My coding skills are very limited so I am looking to find a script that I can adopt to my needs.
But I haven't been able to find something that gets even close.

The wikiuser should put the link with codefences in a special tag named [iframe-embed] like below

```
 [iframe-embed]http:\\some.link.that.should.be.loaded.in.an\iframe[iframe-embed]
```

Then tampermonkey should find those tags and replace them with the proper code to load the link in an iframe instead of the codebox

i have tried to modify a script I found, but that doesn't work

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        gitlab iframes
// 
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://mydomain/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==



    function replace_tag(from_tag,to_tag){
    var eles = document.querySelectorAll(from_tag);

    for (let i=0; i<eles.length; i++){
        try{ // Avoid no-parent elements
            let new_html = eles[i].outerHTML.replaceAll("<"+from_tag, "<"+to_tag);
                new_html = new_html.replaceAll("/"+from_tag+">", "/"+to_tag+">");
            eles[i].outerHTML = new_html;
        }
        catch (e){}
    }
}
console.log("hello, world!");

replace_tag("localdisplay","iframe");
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Good to know! Any pointers how to achieve this?

Comment: This might do what I am looking for. but it seems quite complicated. https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/18835-deviantart-iframe-embedding